# iPhone synced with another user account: which user?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, data-synchronization, big-sur

I was using "noether", a MacBook Pro and "panthere", an iPhone regularly synchronized with iTunes and only with an USB cable.

"noether" was running High Sierra ( macOS 10.13.6 ),
and "panthere" iOS 16.6.

I recently upgraded "noether" to Big Sur ( macOS 11.7.8 ).

Now after plugging "panthere" on "noether" through an USB cable,
I find it in Finder and configured the synchronization process as follows:
[image: Finder synchronization configuration 1]
[image: Finder synchronization configuration 2]

When I clicked on the `[Apply]` button, I got the following popup window:
[image: Finder synchronization warning]

I have always synchronized "panthere" from one uniq user account on "noether".

What might be this "another user account"?

There is no error message logged in `/var/log/system.log` on this warning.

How may I analyze the origin of what is an ununderstandable or false warning?

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is the token created in your home folder to pair the device with the user data has been deleted or corrupted.

If I encountered this, I’d probably work with Apple support to get the location details for my exact version of macOS if I didn’t have a string of good backups of both "noether" and “panthere”

You might be able to get this token back from your backups (hopefully) or be forced to optionally try and recover any files that aren’t on your Mac now and then over write the *old data* with the *current data* from "noether” and allow macOS to create a new pairing record.

---

If I had good backups of both, I would merge and see how that goes.